# how to add multiple objects to nested json array using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, mongodb

I need to insert multiple objects into a mongodb json array using jquery & ajax. I only want to update the mealReviews array. While keeping everything else the same. But when I use the PUT method it replaces my existing code with the newly inputted information.

```
 {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "57afc7636"
},
"mealIDa": "ACT",
"mealIDb": "TMNT2",
"genre": "Action",
"title": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles 2 The Secret of the Ooze",
"description": "The Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (Mark Caso, Michelan Sisti, Leif Tilden, Kenn Troum) again battle their archenemy, the rogue ninja Shredder (Francois Chau). Shredder attempts revenge by obtaining the same radioactive ooze that created the Turtles and unleashing two new monstrous mutants: Tokka, an oversized snapping turtle, and Rahzar, a fearsome wolf-like creature. When Shredder plans to use the remaining ooze on himself, the Turtles must harness their ninja fighting skills to stop him.",
"poster": "TMNT2.jpg",
"mealPoster": "tmnt2.jpg",
"mealSrc": "02 Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II The Secret of the Ooze.mp4",
"releaseDate": "March 22, 1991",
"language": "English",
"subtitle": false,
"srt": "Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II The Secret of the Ooze.srt",
"director": "Michael Pressman",
"actors": "Paige Turco \"April O'Neil\", Vanilla Ice, Michelan Sisti \"Michelangelo, Soho Man\", Robbie Rist \"Michelangelo\", Kevin Clash \"Splinter\"",
"studio": "Golden Harvest Company, New Line Cinema, Northshore Investments Ltd.",
"hrs": 1,
"mins": 28,
"ratings": "PG \u2013 Parents Cautioned",
"dateAdded": "2017-07-18T20:59:17.473Z",
    "mealReviews": [
    {
        "username": "user1",
        "accountType": "viewer",
        "subject": "Great movie!",
        "rating": "4",
        "review": "the best of the time",
        "reviewDate": "2017-07-24T21:03:00.786Z"
       }
      ]
     }

   var mealReviews = [];
   var mealData = ({
       "username": mealUsername,
       "accountType": mealAccountType,
       "subject": mealSubject,
       "rating": mealRating,
       "review": mealReview,
       "reviewDate": reviewDate
   });


    mealReviews.push(new Object(mealData));
```

Then I update the mongodb using the AJAX PUT method, is that correct when updating an array?

```
      $.ajax( { url: 'https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/movie_meals/collections/meals/'+ meal_id + '?apiKey=JVUavJ75zT7u4s2_0Ihmzjn6sS9TEEpn',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "mealReviews": mealReviews
      }),
          type: "PUT",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data){
            $('#mealDetails').hide();
            $('#admin').hide();
            $('#meals').show();
          },
          error:function(xhr,status,err){
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post back the whole object you've retrieved before with changed `mealReviews` property.

```
var meal = // do whatever magic to get your meal object from Mongo
meal.mealReviews = mealReviews;
// save your 'meal' object in the way you described
```